# My code adds only a single key value pair of values while I require list of values to be added. How can I add the entire list?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, arraylist, foreach

I am trying to add a list of values in a dictionary variable. The dictionary contains a string and a list of recommendations as a key value pair. See the below code as an example:

```
  Dictionary<string, List<Recommendations>> rec = new Dictionary<string, List<Recommendations>>();
  List<Recommendations> ItemsList = db.Items.ToLIst();
  // Here I have added all the items to dictionary as follows
  rec.Add(name, ItemsList);
  //And Here I want to filter the results as follows :
  var OrderedList = rec.Where(x=>x.Key!=name)
```

The Problem is that Ordered list only gets a single key Value pair while I want a List of Key value pairs Which I am going to iterate in the following code as follows.

```
  List<Recommendations> Recommendations = new Recommendations();
  foreach(entry in OrderedList)
  {
       Recommendations.Add(Name=entry.Key, 
       Rating=CalculateScore(arguments));
  }
```

Uptill Now foreach part works fine but OrderedList should bring all the results from the db. Please tell me how can I do it. I have tried using an array but it does not iterate and add all the records to dictionary list. I want a list of Dictionaries in the OrderedList which in this case is a KeyValuePair Enumerable.

Comment: Do you want something like this? Recommendations.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(entry.Key, CalculateScore(arguments));

Comment: @jdweng I Want to add list of items Here as I am doing as follows                            
` // Here I have added all the items to dictionary as follows rec.Add(name, ItemsList);` in fact it adds only a single value in OrderedList . Foreach part works fine

Comment: Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> rec = OrderedList.GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.CalculateScore(arguments))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());